# Finish running whatever is in the if statement and then execute else

Tags: javascript, function, ecmascript-6, async-await, graphql

I have the following code:

```
const mainFunc = (fn) => {
  return async (query_name, ...args) => {
    const result = await axios_Func(query_name);
    try {
      return fn(result, ...args);
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e);
    }
  };
};

const createOne = mainFunc((result) => {
  let table_id = result.data.internal_id;
  console.log('Created');
  axios_Func({ graphQL query }).then((response) => {
     createFunc({ query: graphQL_query, table_id).then((res) => res);
  });
});

const createFunc = mainFunc(async(result, table_id) => {
  let dev = await getTabs({ query: tables(123) });
  let prod = await getTabs({ query: tables(321) });
  let prod_id = [];
  result.data.forEach((d) => {
    if (d.connector != null && !(d.name in dev)) {
      prod_id.push(prod[d.name]["internal_id"]);
    }
  });
  prod_id = [...new Set(prod_id)];
  console.log(prod_id);
  if (prod_id.length !== 0) prod_id.forEach((x) =>createOne({ query: graphQL(x) }).then((res) => res));
  else otherFunc(result, table_id);
});

const otherFunc = pipefyFunction(async (result, table_id) => {
  let dev = await getTabs({ query: tables(123) });
  result.data.forEach((d) => {
    if (d.name in dev) {
      axios_DevFunc({ graphQL query }).then((response) => {
        console.log(`created from dev`);
        console.log(JSON.stringify(response.data, null, 4));
      });
    } else if (d.connector == null) {
      axios_Func({ graphQL query }).then((response) => {
        if (response.data.errors) {
          // rerun function on errors
        } else console.log(JSON.stringify(response.data, null, 4));
      });
    } 
  });
```

On `node index.js`, `createOne(123)` is called which calls `createFunc`. I want the `if` statement to completely run before going to the `else`. What I mean, is `prod_id` returns:

```
Created
[123, 321]
Created
Created
[]
[456]
Created
[423, 3432, 789]
Created
Created
Created
```

After this function is completely done, I want to be able to call `otherFunc`. I am getting this error:

```
 return (encoder || JSON.stringify)(rawValue);
                                    ^

TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON
    --> starting at object with constructor 'TLSSocket'
    |     property 'parser' -> object with constructor 'HTTPParser'
    --- property 'socket' closes the circle
    at stringify (<anonymous>)
```

Also, `createFunc` has not finished running and has already called `otherFunc`. How do I finish running `createFunc` and then call `otherFunc`?

Comment: `if` and `else` are mutually exclusive, it only runs one or the other. So what you want makes no sense.

Comment: @Barmar, I actually want to just call `otherFunc` after `createFunc` finished running.

Comment: @Barmar, not sure how to go about doing that so I tried the `if-else`

Comment: `.then((res) => res)` is an expensive NOOP.

Comment: Which `if` are you talking about, `if (prod_id.length !== 0)` or `if (d.name in dev)`?

Comment: You have lots of async function calls, so the loop iterations aren't going to wait for previous iterations. Is that the problem?

Comment: @Barmar I want `if (prod_id.length !== 0)` to finish running

Comment: @Barmar, the reason I have so many `async-await` is so that the functions finish running before starting new iterations. But that is not working out the way I expected.

Comment: You're not awaiting the Axios functions, so they run asynchrously without waiting for them.

Comment: @Barmar, I am unsure what you mean? Can you give me an example?

Answer (score 1):

Have `createOne()` return the Promise from the Axios call. Then you can collect all of them in an array and use `Promise.all()` to wait for them.

```js
const createOne = mainFunc((result) => {
    let table_id = result.data.internal_id;
    console.log('Created');
    return axios_Func({
      graphQL query
    }).then((response) => {
        createFunc({
            query: graphQL_query,
            table_id).then((res) => res);
        });
    });
}

const createFunc = mainFunc(async(result, table_id) => {
  let dev = await getTabs({
    query: tables(123)
  });
  let prod = await getTabs({
    query: tables(321)
  });
  let prod_id = new Set();
  result.data.forEach((d) => {
    if (d.connector != null && !(d.name in dev)) {
      prod_id.add(prod[d.name]["internal_id"]);
    }
  });
  prod_id = [...prod_id];
  console.log(prod_id);
  if (prod_id.length !== 0) {
    await Promise.all(prod_id.map((x) => createOne({
      query: graphQL(x)
    })));
  } else {
    otherFunc(result, table_id);
  }
});
```